# AngularJs, Ionic and Firebase data is having trouble moving through states

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, factory

My Fire base data is displaying on my Dash.html strangely, it is displaying the cards with all the information on the database, but when i click on them the information isn't being moved across, and its also displaying the last item in the database 10 times, where i an then click on them and see the data be moved across...

I am trying to achieve a list of people, where i can then click on their card to retrieve more information about that person (in Ionic.)

My Factory:

```
.factory('PetService', function($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) 
{

  var ref = new Firebase("firebaseURL");
  var pets = $firebaseArray(ref);

ref.once("value", function(allMessagesSnapshot) {
  allMessagesSnapshot.forEach(function(messageSnapshot) {

 for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    pets[i] = {
      id: i,
      'Name': messageSnapshot.child("Name").val(),
      'Offer': messageSnapshot.child("Offer").val(),
      'Image': messageSnapshot.child("Image").val(),
      'Expat': messageSnapshot.child("Expat").val(),
    };

  }


  });
});


  return {
    all: function () {
      return pets
    },
    get: function (petId) {

      return pets[petId];
    }
  };

})
```

My DashCtrl:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, PetService) {
      $scope.pets = PetService.all();
})
```

My ProfileCtrl:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope, $state, PetService) {
   $scope.pet = PetService.get($stateParams.petsId);
})
```

My Profile State:

```
  .state('app.profile', {
    url: "/profile/:petsId",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "routes/profile.html",
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
      }
    }
  })
```

My Collection repeat Line (Dash.html):

```
<div class="col"  collection-repeat="pet in pets| orderBy:'Name'" item-width="45%" item-height="35%"  ui-sref="app.profile({petsId: pet.id })">
```

My profile.html:

```
<div class="list" >
      <label class="item item-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-earth"></i>
       <h4 class="invf">Location</h4>
       <div class="invtext">{{pet.Location}}</div>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-calendar"></i>
        <h4 class="invf">Age</h4>
        <div class="invtext">{{pet.Age}}</div>
      </label>
       <label class="item item-icon-left"  style="word-wrap: break-word; width: 350px;">    
       <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
        <h4 class="invf">About me</h4>
        <div class="invtext" >{{pet.About}}</div>
      </label>
       <label class="item item-icon-left">
       <i class="icon ion-pizza"></i>
       <h4 class="invf" >What I offer</h4>
          <div class="invtext">{{pet.Offer}}</div>
      </label>
       <label class="item item-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-cash"></i>
        <h4 class="invf">Rate</h4>
        <div class="invtext">{{pet.Rate}}</div>
      </label>
      </div>
```

If you could provide a code example of how i could solve this by fixing up my factory, that would be amazing!

Thank you so much for your help!

(Sorry for my bad English and explaining!)